# Newtonsoft.Json how to deserialize json Key : Value to C# Property

Tags: c#, json

my json file likes bellow

```
{
    "Tag": "en",
    "Errors": {
        "MethodRefreshIsNull": "refreshMethod is null."
    } 
}
```

and i want convert

```
"MethodRefreshIsNull": "refreshMethod is null."
```

to

```
public KeyInfo MethodRefreshIsNull { get; set; }
```

and the class KeyInfo is

```
public class KeyInfo 
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    *public void OutputToConsole()
    {
         console.WriteLine(Value);
    }*
}
```

then the string   **"refreshMethod is null."**   will be the **Value**  .

is there any simple way to convert that ?

----------------update

```
public void OutputToConsole()
{
     console.WriteLine(Value);
}
```

class KeyInfo has methods and other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you see `{ }`, it means its an object. Objects are represented by c# classes. You can use the following model to deserialize your json with.

```
public class RootObject 
{
  public string Tag {get; set;}
  public KeyValueObject Errors {get;set;}
}

public class KeyValueObject 
{
  public string MethodRefreshIsNull {get;set;}
}

//then, you would deserialize like this,

RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonStringContent);
Console.WriteLine($"Printing Tag: {obj.Tag}");
Console.WriteLine($"Printing Error: {obj.Errors.MethodRefreshIsNull}");

// prints
en
refreshMethod is null
```

"refreshMethod is null" is the value for `MethodRefreshIsNull`, which is a property of `Errors`.

Comment: thanks for response. see my update , it tells why i want a class not just a string.

Comment: The json you have does not show the value as an object but a string.

Comment: that's right .  And i want convert it to object , not a string.